# Running a command shell from C#

Tags: c#, command-line, system.diagnostics

I want to run a command from C# with below code but the application waits infinitely:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process p = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
p.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
p.StartInfo.Arguments = command;
p.Start();
p.WaitForExit();
p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
```

I did a debug and the last break point passed is `p.WaitForExit()`. What am I doing wrong?
By the way, I tried run the command manually and I get the result in miliseconds.

Comment: what is your `command`? does it closes the Command Prompt by itself?

Comment: Instead of running a command prompt to run something, why don't you just run the something directly?

Comment: @crashmstr What do you mean? I want to run the command from C# because I need do staff automatically.

Comment: I mean instead of running `command` through `cmd.exe`, run `command` directly as the `FileName` (note: this is assuming `command` is an external program. *If not*, then you probably want to use .Net to do the equivalent instead).

Answer (score 0):

Try prepending a /C to your arguments - without it, cmd.exe won't terminate

Comment: I'm including `/C` currently

Comment: Hmm...sounds like the command itself isn't terminating - is it something that needs an explicit exit - like diskpart or some other command that creates an "environment" for execution?  You might not see or feel it's lack of normal termination if you normally execute it in a command window - since you can always just close that yourself.

I suggested appending the /c, but in reality, it should be prepended - that is, before the command text

Comment: Might be worthwhile to run it with the window showing - see if you're getting unanticipated stuff in your command string - maybe something that's causing a prompt of some kind?